# Fundamental bug rendering latest M2E entirely unusable?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

**Eclipse:** Juno (3.8.0)
**M2E build:** 1.2.0.20120903-1050

When I try to right click on a Maven Project and select `Maven > Update Project...` and then click `OK` , I get the following showstopping error:

> 'Updating Maven Project has encountered a problem. An internal error
>   occured during: "Updating Maven Project".

This one is straight from the box - so it must be **fundamentally broken?** This error presents the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:651)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:358)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:585)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:542)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:528)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:833)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.getConfiguredMojo(MavenImpl.java:344)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.reflectManifestGeneration(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:406)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.generateManifest(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:364)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:183)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.mavenProjectChanged(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.refresh(MavenProjectManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: Does the project build etc. without problems on comand line ? mvn clena package ?

Comment: Yes - however I use a maven-ear-plugin which creates the eventual EAR and deploys it to a Weblogic server. I cannot do absolutely anything mavenish within Eclipse without immediately getting the above stack trace. It looks like m2e is throwing it.

Comment: How have you imported the project into Eclipse via **Import->Existing Maven Project** ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes I have imported the project in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using m2e 1.2.0 without problems, so it must be a local problem on your PC. Try:

1. Try restarting Eclipse
2. A colleague had a similar problem yesterday on a Linux machine. To my surprise, a reboot fixed it.
3. Make sure that the JAR files in `~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/` aren't corrupt.

When you do the last step, make sure you look in the correct repository. It's possible to configure the two Maven's (Eclipse's and the one on the command line) differently. Check the "Maven" preferences in Eclipse for the paths of the settings files.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I found that a re-install of Eclipse (same version and same verion of both the m2e plugin and Maven on the command line) remedied the problem. I would have to assume that Eclipse and/or the plexus plugin became corrupt. This may have been brought about by removing and adding transient dependencies when uninstalling an old version of m2e before installing the latest.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same error.

When I first created the maven project using m2e, the maven installation was configured to my local apache-maven-3.0.3 folder.

Recently I switched ide to spring tool suite, which has apache-maven-3.0.4 bundled. So I use 3.0.4 instead, then the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;" appears. Now I get the configuration back to previous version of maven, the error disappears.

Comment: The version of Maven (external install) that I used remained consistent (v2.2.1) across m2e plugins. However I then re-installed Eclipse and tried again (including updating to the build of m2e provided in the header of the question), and it worked. It is possible that either the JAR in my .m2 repository and/or my install of Eclipse became corrupt.

Comment: @Mark what was the conclusion [years later] hehe!?